# Send different emails via Excel VBA based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I run a train-the-trainer training and have a spreadsheet which I use to create a PDF attendance certificate and an email to confirm whether or not they have passed the course to take on the trainer role.  This is all done via Excel VBA which I cannibalised from various Google searches and Youtube videos... I have managed to get it to work ok except I want it to send separate email contents depending on whether or not they passed.

So, in the worksheet labelled "Attendance" I have the following table/headers:

| CourseID | Outcome | Title | First Name | Last Name | Subject | Area | UserID | Email | Filename |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| N100P | Not Ready | Mrs | Alice | One | English | England | 1236547 | alice@one.comm | N100P_AliceOne_1236547.pdf |
| N100P | Recommend | Mr | Bob | Two | Maths | Scotland | 6548789 | bob@two.ukk | N100P_BobTwo_6548789.pdf |

CourseID = cell `A1`
Filename = cell `J1`

In the macro I have the below:

```
Sub DraftEmailWithCerts()
Dim EApp As Object
Set EApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim EItem As Object
Dim path As String
path = Worksheets("PDF").Range("J2").Value 'path to folder of PDFs to be saved
Dim RList As Range
Set RList = Worksheets("Attendance").Range("A2", Worksheets("Attendance").Range("a2").End(xlDown))
Dim R As Range

For Each R In RList
    
    Set EItem = EApp.CreateItem(0)
        With EItem
        .To = R.Offset(0, 8)
        .Subject = Worksheets("Attendance").Range("A2").Value & " " & Worksheets("PDF").Range("J3").Value & ": Outcome" 'Attendance!A2 is training course ID and PDF!J3 is name of the training
        .Attachments.Add (path & R.Offset(0, 9))
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "train@the.trainer.com"

        If Worksheets("Attendance").Range("B2").Value = "Not Ready" Then

        .HTMLBody = "<p>Thank you for your hard work and participation at the recent training.  Unfortunately the panel has concluded that you are not ready to take up the trainer role.</p>"
        
        Else
        
        .HTMLBody = "<p>Thank you for your hard work and participation at the recent training.  The panel has recommended you to take up the trainer role, congratulations.</p>"
    
        End If

        .Display
        End With

Next R
Set EApp = Nothing
Set EItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

I have a separate macro to create the necessary PDF and it works.

What I am looking for is for the macro to send a "Not ready" email for Alice (because in the Outcome column B it says "Not ready") and a "Ready" email for Bob (his Outcome was "Recommend")... at the moment it just sends everyone a "Not ready" email...

I am very new to VBA so any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

- You are iterating the `Rlist` per each cell (!) of `RList`.
- You always check `Worksheets("Attendance").Range("B2").Value = "Not Ready" Then` - the result will obviously always be true as the value in `B2` does not change while code execution.

Therefore you have to iterate over each row of the list (`For Each R In RList.Rows`) and read the values from that row (`If R.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Not Ready" Then`). `R` returns a range e.g. A2:J2 for the first row of your list.

```vb
Sub DraftEmailWithCerts()
Dim EApp As Object
Set EApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim EItem As Object
Dim path As String
path = Worksheets("PDF").Range("J2").Value 'path to folder of PDFs to be saved


Dim RList As Range
Set RList = Worksheets("Attendance").Range("A2", Worksheets("Attendance").Range("a2").End(xlDown))
Dim R As Range

For Each R In RList.Rows
    
    Set EItem = EApp.CreateItem(0)
    With EItem
        .To = R.Cells(1, 9)
        .Subject = R.Cells(1, 1) & " " & Worksheets("PDF").Range("J3").Value & ": Outcome" 'Attendance!A2 is training course ID and PDF!J3 is name of the training
        .Attachments.Add (path & R.Cells(1, 10))
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "train@the.trainer.com"

        If R.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Not Ready" Then
            .HTMLBody = "<p>Thank you for your hard work and participation at the recent training.  Unfortunately the panel has concluded that you are not ready to take up the trainer role.</p>"
        Else
            .HTMLBody = "<p>Thank you for your hard work and participation at the recent training.  The panel has recommended you to take up the trainer role, congratulations.</p>"
        End If

        .Display
    End With

Next R
Set EApp = Nothing
Set EItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!  It took me ages to cobble that together and you've both fixes it in a matter of minutes!!!  Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the row numbers rather than cells themselves.

So, I'd try replacing

```
Dim RList As Range
Set RList = Worksheets("Attendance").Range("A2", Worksheets("Attendance").Range("a2").End(xlDown))
Dim R As Range
For Each R In RList
  '...
    .Subject = Worksheets("Attendance").Range("A2").Value & " " & Worksheets("PDF").Range("J3").Value & ": Outcome"
  '...
    If Worksheets("Attendance").Range("B2").Value = "Not Ready" Then
  '...
Next R
```

with something like

```
Dim shAtt as WorkSheet
Dim r as Long
Dim rFirst as Long
Dim rLast as Long
Set shAtt = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Attendance")
rFirst = 2
rLast = shAtt.Range("A" & r).End(xlDown).Row
For r = rFirst to rLast
  '...
    .Subject = shAtt.Range("A" & r).Value & " " & Worksheets("PDF").Range("J3").Value & ": Outcome"
  '...
    If shAtt.Range("B" & r).Value = "Not Ready" Then
  '...
Next r
```